# Cannot read property 'user' of undefined & DELETE /api/profile/id 500 168.563 ms - 148

Tags: node.js

router.delete('/id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {

```
  User.findOne({ _id: req.body.id.user }).then(user => {

      if (user) {
          if (user.hasProfile) {
              Profile.findOneAndRemove({ user: req.body.id.user }).then(() => {
                  User.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id.user }).then(() =>
                    res.json({ success: true })
                  );
              });
          }
          else {
              User.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id.user }).then(() =>

                res.json({ success: true })
              );
          }
      }
  });
}
```

);

Comment: `req.body.id` is `undefined`. Might bee worth console logging `req.body` to see exactly where the `user` is, if there is one

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` of the `User` is in the `url`, you access it through `req.params` and NOT `req.body`

Comment: can you update the code and show how are you accessing it?